# PostgeSQL trigger before insert unique value

Tags: sql, postgresql, triggers

Is there any variant to create a trigger before insert and if the value is a value that exists already in table, just update it. I know about 'ON DUBLICATE KEY' or a 'ON CONFLICT' in PostgreSQL but I need a trigger just because it's a task in my university.
I tried to create it, but I get just an error about duplicate keys.

```
CREATE or replace FUNCTION trigger_function()
   RETURNS TRIGGER
   LANGUAGE PLPGSQL
AS $$
BEGIN
   IF new.name in (select name from "Test")
       then
           update "Test" set intt = new.intt where name = new.name;
       end if ;
   return new;
END;
$$

CREATE TRIGGER trigger_name
   BEFORE insert
   ON "Test"
   for each row
       EXECUTE PROCEDURE trigger_function();
```

Is it possible to create such trigger?

Comment: remove the existing unique constraint - it is being checked before your trigger

Answer (score 0):

Read the docs [plpgsql trigger function](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/14/plpgsql-trigger.html):

> Row-level triggers fired BEFORE can return null to signal the trigger manager to skip the rest of the operation for this row (i.e., subsequent triggers are not fired, and the INSERT/UPDATE/DELETE does not occur for this row).

So `RETURN NULL` after the UPDATE statement inside the `if` and`RETURN NEW` when the `if` is false. Then the `INSERT` will happen if the name is unique.